# Join two arrays with lodash and use an array as key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js, lodash

I would like join with lodash

arrays:

```
var Lines = ["a","b","c"];
var Values = [[5,5,5,5],[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]];
```

Expected Result:

```
All = [ { a: [5,5,5,5]}, { b: [1,1,1,1]}, { c: [2,2,2,2]} ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Note: Doing your own research and making your own attempt are requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for a lodash solution, here it is.

```
var Lines = ["a","b","c"];
var Values = [[5,5,5,5],[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]];
var All = _.zipObject(Lines, Values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need whole lodash lib to handle it. Native `Array#map` is enough.

```js
const Lines = ["a","b","c"];
const Values = [[5,5,5,5],[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]];

let res = Lines.map((v, i) => ({ [v]: Values[i] }));

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```